# Python question about adding elements of "array"

Tags: python

```py
[(-2.3391885553668246e-10, 8.473071450645254e-10), (-2.91634014818891e-10, 8.913956007163883e-10), (-3.470135547671147e-10, 9.186162538099684e-10), (-3.9905561869610444e-10, 8.425016542750256e-10), (-4.4700997526371524e-10, 8.681513230068634e-10), (-4.903967399792693e-10, 9.204845678073805e-10),....
```

I have given this result in a code that I wrote. I would like to add up all of the components on the left side of the two terms in the parenthesis. How do I do this? I don't know what type of array this is and so I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a list of tuples. You can try the following:

```py
tuples = [
    (-2.3391885553668246e-10, 8.473071450645254e-10),
    (-2.91634014818891e-10, 8.913956007163883e-10), 
    (-3.470135547671147e-10, 9.186162538099684e-10), 
    (-3.9905561869610444e-10, 8.425016542750256e-10), 
    (-4.4700997526371524e-10, 8.681513230068634e-10), 
    (-4.903967399792693e-10, 9.204845678073805e-10),
]
result = sum(t[0] for t in tuples)
```